# Iomega storCenter : Files with french punctuation "Not exist" when accessed in remote

Tags: network-attached-storage

I have an Iomega NAS Storcenter at home where I copied all my files (photos, video, documents, etc). When I access my files on the NAS using explorer from a home computer, I have access to all files but when I access the NAS remotely using Internet Explorer (or any browser) I receive the message that the file does not exist when the file name includes french punctuation (é,è, â, etc). I have colleagues who have other brands of NAS that does not have this type of problem. Unfortunately, almost half of the 8000 files have punctuation. Do you have a suggestion to help me?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Your browsers have a different [character set encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) than your home computer does.

You need to figure out what character set the OS on your home PC has, and change your browser's character set encoding to match.  (This may involve installing a [language-specific version of the browser](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-your-Internet-Explorer-language-settings), depending on whether or not the character set encoding applies to what you type into the address bar or not.)

Alternately, and this is a pain, but you can figure out what [HTML code each foreign letter corresponds to](http://www.danshort.com/ASCIImap/) and substitute that for the character in the path.  So `é` becomes `&#232;` or `&egrave;` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work. In fact, after reading a lot of stuff on the iomega web site, I found a article stating that extended caracters set is not supported.  So I gess there's nothing I ca do.  I just bought a Synology NAS and I'm going to sell the Iomega